# How do I create static web server in expo app?

Tags: react-native, expo

Can I create a static web server inside an expo app? I know I can do that in react-native. I knew it from [here](https://spin.atomicobject.com/2019/08/28/static-http-server-react-native/).

But i want know about the expo managed workflow